# Personal Package Archive (PPA) export

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, ppa, repository, migration

I plan to **upgrade a machine from 12.04 to 14.04 LTS**. I explore the best way to export the Personal Package Archive (PPA) repository list and import it back after the migration?

Does backing-up **/etc/apt/sources.list** and restoring **source.list** with the same permission is an acceptable practice?

Answer (score 0):

> Does backing-up `/etc/apt/sources.list` and restoring `sources.list` with the same permission is an acceptable practice?

No, `/etc/apt/sources.list` file should vary for each Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Y-PPA manager](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager) for that. You can install it via The following [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Supported Ubuntu distributions:

Utopic(14.10), Trusty(14.04), Saucy(13.10), Raring(13.04), Quantal(12.10), Precise(12.04), Oneiric(11.10), Natty(11.04), Maverick(10.10), Lucid(10.04), Karmic(9.10)

It has many features that could help you in your situation:

> ...
>
> - Backup an restore PPAs (automatically imports missing GPG keys)
> - Re-enable working PPAs after Ubuntu upgrade: when you upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release, the PPAs are disabled so using this feature, the
>     PPAs that work with the new Ubuntu version you're using are
>     re-enabled, leaving the others disabled
> - Update release name in working PPAs: somewhat similar to the feature above, this one is useful if you've backup up the PPAs in say Ubuntu
>     Precise and restored them in Ubuntu Quantal (just an example) - in
>     this case, using this feature you can replace "precise" in each PPA
>     source with "quantal", but only for the PPAs that have packages for
>     Quantal.
>
> ...

[image]

**Reference**:

- [Y PPA Manager in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager)
- [Y PPA Manager 0.9.9.1 Released With Ubuntu 13.10 Fixes ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/y-ppa-manager-0991-released-with-ubuntu.html)